# Why would This Flask Page not render and show a 500 ERROR?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm relatively new to Flask and SQLAlchemy, but we've been learning them in bootcamp.  I thought I would give a try creating a website with them, but having difficulty. Other pages are working fine and this page did work on local testing machine, but is popping up with 500 error? I'm thinking it may be in app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], but having trouble finding a good explanation on this. Any help much appreciated!

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, flash, session, url_for
import cgi
import os
import math
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@/31.220.50.227:3306'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.secret_key = 'y337kGcys&zP3B'

class Catalog(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    img_location = db.Column(db.String(120))
    pdf_location = db.Column(db.String(120))
    title = db.Column(db.String(120))


    def __init__(self, img_location, pdf_location, title):
        self.img_location = img_location
        self.pdf_location = pdf_location
        self.title = title



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/catalogs')
def catalogs():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)

    catalogs = Catalog.query.paginate(page=page,per_page= 5)
    next_url = url_for('catalogs', page=catalogs.next_num) \
        if catalogs.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('catalogs', page=catalogs.prev_num) \
        if catalogs.has_prev else None
    img_location = request.args.get("img_location")
    down_location = request.args.get("down_location")
    return render_template('catalogs.html',title="Camera Eccentric", catalogs=catalogs, next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="catalogs">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            {% for catalog in catalogs.items %}
            <div class="col-sm text-center">
                <a href="{{catalog.pdf_location}}"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{catalog.img_location}}">
                <h3>{{catalog.title}}</h3></a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm text-center">  
                    {% if prev_url %}
                    <a href="{{ prev_url }}"><h3>Previous</h3></a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm text-center">
                    {% for page_num in catalogs.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
                    {% if page_num %}
                    {% if catalogs.page == page_num %}
                    <a class="btn btn-custom mb-4" href="{{ url_for('catalogs', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                    {% else %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-custom mb-4" href="{{ url_for('catalogs', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% else %}
                    ...
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm text-center">
                    {% if next_url %}
                    <a href="{{ next_url }}"><h3>Next</h3></a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div> 
                <div class="row mx-0">
                    <div class="col-12 bg-light text-dark">

                        <p>Researching classic cameras and lenses can be a daunting process.
                            We hope these pages will not only inform photographers about vintage camera equipment,
                            but inspire others to start using them in their future photographic and creative endeavors.
                        </p>
                        <p>We will continue to update this page with photographs, experiences, and catalogs.
                            We hope you find these helpful and greatly appreciate any contributions from other
                            photographers : )
                        </p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201773/discussion-on-question-by-compeccentric-why-would-this-flask-page-not-render-and).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Seems like either flask, sqlalchemy connects to tables with lowercase names and I had a table with an uppercase name.  Changed the name to lowercase and the page works!